4 Babies' Brisim on 4 different days!
Is there any situation in which 4 different babies can be born within the same 2 hours in the same hospital, without any one them being sick, yet, their Bris is on 4 different days? In other words, each one's Bris will be on a different day than the others,

Do you have a reason to think there might be?

For argument's sake, the 4 babies names are: Baby 1, Baby 2, Baby 3, Baby 4.
Now, let us say that the 4 babies were all born in between 6:00 P.M. and 8:00 P.M. on a Friday night. Let's break this down into steps:

Step #1 - Baby 1 is born before Shkia (6:15), so his Bris will be on the following Friday.
Step #2 - Baby 2 is born after Tzeis HaKochavim (7:20), so his Bris will be on the following Shabbos.

The rule that you can do a Bris on Shabbos is only when the actual date of the Bris falls out on Shabbos. If a baby is born during Bein HaShmashos (between Shkia & Tzeis HaKoChavim), it is considered as if he was born after Tzeis HaKoChavim. But this is still not his exact date for the Bris, since we aren't completely sure if he was born before or after the next day started. So, if a baby was born on Friday night Bein HashMashos, his Bris will not be on the following Shabbos, since a Bris only pushes off Shabbos if it is the correct date, and this isn't the 100% correct date.
Now, let us say that Shabbos and Sunday are Yom Tov:

Step #3 - Baby 3 is born during Bein HashMashos Friday night, and his mother is from Israel, so Sunday is not Yom Tov for them since they only hold of one day Yom Tov. So, his Bris will be in 2 Sundays, since this Bris won't push off Shabbos, so we do it the next Sunday.
Step #4 - Baby 4 is born during Bein HashMashos Friday, but his Bris can't be on Shabbos or on Sunday (because it's Yom Tov), so his Bris will be in 2 Mondays.


Number three is sketchy, at best. Given that the mohel is most likely a chutznik (unless the above scenario takes place in E"Y) then he wouldn't be able to perform the miloh when it would be forbidden to him. Similarly, Y"T sheini wouldn't be nidcheh the fourth baby, if he were born in E"Y

@NoachMiFrankfurt Maybe the baby made aliyah in between. If we allow travel though we could just as easily have a baby born in Japan at the same moment a baby is born in New York, on different dates. Or maybe the mohel follows the ramban and allows milah shelo bizmanah on yom tov sheni.

They are all non Jews and convert on different days.
